# Azure event hub, receive events only after processing previous events?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-eventhub

Im using azure event hub for a project via this npm package [@azure/events-hub](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/event-hubs)

Im wondering if theres a way to make the event receiver only receive new event when it is done processing a previously received event. The point is i want to process one event at a time. 
My observation currently is that it sends events to the handler the moment they become available.

The api im using is the `client.receive(partitionId, onMessage, onError)` from the docs.
Wondering if there's a way to achieve the mentioned behaviour, with this api.

Comment: If you want to process messages sequentially, then event hubs might not be the best solution as it is designed for mass event processing. You might be better of using an Azure Service Bus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `client.receive()` method returns a RecieverHandler object that you could use to stop the stream using it's `stop()` method. You would then start it again using a fresh `client.receive()`.

Another option would be to use `client.recieveBatch()` where the max batch size is set to 1.

Neither option is ideal- as Peter Bons mentioned, Event Hubs are not designed for a slow drip of data.The service assumes that you will be able to accept messages at the same rate they came in, and that you will have only 1 receiver per partition. Service Bus is indeed a good alternative to look into. You can choose how many messages a recieve at a time and connect multiple receivers, each processing one message at a time, to scale your solution.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is the need to have back pressure and the latest version of the `@azure/event-hubs` package has indeed solved this problem. It ensures that you receive events only after the previously received events are processed. By default, you will receive events in batches of size 10 and this size is configurable.

See the [migration guide from v2 to v5](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/event-hubs/migrationguide.md) if you need to upgrade your current application to use the latest version of the package.